# scss variable in Angular 2

Tags: sass, angular, webpack

I'm using angular 2 + webpack + scss. And by some reason I cannot use scss variable:

```
 $white: #fff;
.test{
 color: $white;
}
```

In style console I see that color is not set (strikeout).

My webpack config:

```
module: {
loaders: [
  { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
  }
]
```

Does someone know what it could be?

Comment: No I just create a sample

Comment: Did you *look* at your compiled CSS?

Comment: { test: /^((?!materialize).)*\.css$/,   loader: 'raw-loader' }

Comment: That can't seriously be your CSS, are you sure you're looking at the right file?

Comment: I'm have very bad imagination  haw webpack do scss magic. I configure webpack as it provided [there](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components). And  I don't have css file at all.

Comment: how do you import the .scss in your component?, and add a 's'  to loader, when you use the array syntax

Comment: We can't help you unless you're able to show your compiled CSS.  There are multiple reasons why styles might be crossed out in the console.

Comment: I am also facing the issue mentioned in the question. Not able to use vars in scss file. I am using the correct webpack.config file as you also suggested. See my post here : stackoverflow.com/questions/40401501/

Answer (score 1):

If the styles are crossed out in your browser, it means that scss is doing what it needs to do but other styles have a higher selector specificity for the same properties you are trying to change.

Comment: I'm not try to change anything. Just create scss variable and use it in test class.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax bug in your webpack config. You have to use `loaders` not `loader`! See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders

```
module: {
loaders: [
  { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // loaders not loader
  }
]
```

Comment: How does this answer the question, exactly?  Were you able to reproduce the OP's problem?  How  does this fix it?

Comment: The syntax of the webpack config ist wrong. See https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders

Comment: So in other words, you should be voting to close this as a typographical error, yes?

Comment: Is there an option to close an question in case of a syntax error ?

Comment: Yes, "off-topic because..." > "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.".  Its usually helpful if you also leave a comment pointing out where the typo is when you do this to help future voters see the error as well.  (Do note that the OP has already made a mistake in posting their code with the question.)

Comment: @cebor - I am also facing the issue mentioned in the question. Not able to use vars in scss file. I am using the correct webpack.config file as you also suggested. See my post here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401501/how-to-use-sass-in-angular2-application