# How to use SASS/SCSS in angular application

Tags: css, node.js, angular, typescript, sass

I am trying to build a color theme functionality in angular2 application using sass. My header.component.scss file is:

```
$head-color: #f11;
h1{
    color: $head-color;
}
```

I have created a file webpack.common.js in root directory and added the following in it:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

My header is being displayed in default black color. However if i change the scss file to following then its displayed in red color.

```
h1{
    color: #f11;
}
```

So basically I am not able to assign dynamic value to variables. Anyone having some idea about this pls share.  TIA

Comment: sass can be compiled to css using build tools. What are you using?

Comment: Webpack is unable to compile it. I am getting error while compiling.
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.10.1

Comment: No. Please refer this link for more insight
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Comment: @user32 could you please share the entire content I should have in webpack.config.js file. TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SASS for components style in Angular 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313971/how-to-use-sass-for-components-style-in-angular-2)

Comment: @MaximeBernard I followed your answer there. Did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using styleUrls use styles and convert the file to a string.

```
styles: [require('./header.component.scss').toString()]
```

For your webpack config I think you have to many loaders. I believe you should be able to just have

```
'raw-loader!sass-loader'
```

My current config is:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'raw-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader'
},
```

Comment: Ok I will try this. @Joey do we need to include the webpack.common.js in index.html file?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. If that is the bundle webpack outputs than yes.

Comment: Joey could you please share the entire config file

Comment: when i use : styles: [require('./header.component.scss').toString()] then it starts looking for home.component.scss.js file. hence give 404 not found. Why does it looks for scss.js file?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `StyleUrls` instead of `Styles`

Change `styleUrls: ['app/header/header.component.scss']` by `styles: [ String(require('./header.component.scss')) ]`

See more https://stackoverflow.com/a/38349028/689429

Update your errors if necessary

Comment: I tried that but it gave me error. Pls see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Command line inside project folder where your existing package.json is: `npm install node-sass sass-loader raw-loader --save-dev`

In webpack.common.js, search for "loaders:" and add this object to the end of the loaders array (don't forget to add a comma to the end of the previous object):

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
}
```

Then in your component:

```
@Component({
  styleUrls: ['./filename.scss'],
})
```

If you want global CSS support then on the top level component (likely app.component.ts) remove encapsulation and include the SCSS:

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  styleUrls: ['./bootstrap.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  template: ``
})
class App {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my own project this is what I used.

**form-automobile.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'form-automobile',
    templateUrl: './form-automobile.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form-automobile.component.scss'],
})
```

**form-automobile.component.scss**

```
$myuglycolor: lime;

label {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: $myuglycolor
}
```

**webpack.config.common.js**

```
{
    // Load component styles here. When loaded with styleUrls in component, array of string of styles is expected.
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: ['css-to-string-loader','css-loader','sass-loader']
}
```